# Как сохранить значение переменной в фрагменте при переходе на другой фрагмент и возвращении?

Tags: android, kotlin

В моём фрагменте от значения Boolean зависит расположение view на экране. У меня получается сохранять эту переменную при выходе из приложения с помощью SharedPreferences. Но также я хочу добиться, чтобы когда переходишь на другие фрагменты и возвращаешься, это значение сохранялось. Пытаюсь сделать это через SavedInstanceState. Логирование показало, что мой код не работает из-за того что Bundle всегда равен null. Это значит, что Bundle уничтожается при переходе на другой фрагмент? И как в этом случае можно сохранить переменную?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
 super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) 
 
 val share = activity?.getSharedPreferences("variant", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
 if (savedInstanceState != null) { isListView = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("key") } 
 else { isListView = share!!.getBoolean("variant", false) } 
 if (isListView) { 
 binding?.rcList?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 1) 
 nameIconGrid = "плитка" 
 } else { 
 binding!!.rcList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2) 
 nameIconGrid = "список" 
 }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) { 
 super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) 
 outState.putBoolean("key", isListView) }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов так то много.
Использовать sharedViewModel 
Обновлять значение в тех же shearedPreferences,
Передавать значение через [safe args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data),
передавать значение через bundle
Если мне нужно только значение, то я бы передавал через safe args значение. Если еще и логика разделяется между фрагментами, то проще всего использовать общую viewModel. Кстати binding лучше исползьовать подобным образом:

```
private var _binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
//или так, если хочется собственный коментарий указать
private val binding get() = checkNotNull(_binding) { "Комментарий" }
...
override onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView()
   _binding = null
}
```